# Django! How to add a custom admin system in a website?

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms, django-admin, admin

I am a beginner of django. I made a project. This is a online shop. Here, the builtin system of admin is nice. And I want to keep it for administration of my site(like add product, add staff, edit product details.

Now what I want-- I want to add a another admin system for the user. They will sign up with some details (like email, name, password, date of birth etc). They will be able to login with email and password to buy a product. But they can not enter administration panel. They will be separated. Also they will have cart to store their order info. Now, I tried hard to do Somthing like this. But I am getting confused with what I should do or avoid. I didn't get a helpfull thing in internet for me. So, I just cleared my project and starting again from the very beginning. Now how can I make like a separated admin system in a app(my case: account) for users?

Comment: You can add it as an separated app or choose shop apps from these site: djangopackages.org (i.e: https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-shop/)

Comment: For end-users of your site, usually you never want them having to access your admin backend. You should however use the same user database for your frontend-, as well as your backend users. Django provides the two flags `is_staff` 
 and `is_superuser` to distinguish, if they can access the backend.